# How to custom UITableView with number of rows (around 20) and each row should contain UIButton?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I want to declare the `UIButton` only once that will `show in each table row` and then will use `button.tag` to make button work accordingly.

Comment: A view can only appear once. Therefore each row must have its own button.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have the button created for each table row. You can use prototype cell if you are using Storyboard.

The reason it will not work with single button as a view can be added to one super view at a time. If you add button to second row cell it will be removed from the first row.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Custom cell and design you cell as per your requirement then after in Table View Data Source Method you can set the tag and then after you can create your button method and as per tag use Switch case to do different different action.

Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is a UITableView with UiButton in each row [LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdTbt.png)

**Code here:-**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *simpleIdentifier=@"tableItems";

        UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleIdentifier];

        if (cell==Nil)
        {
            cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleIdentifier];
        }

        UIButton *tableButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        tableButton.frame=CGRectMake(140, 5, 60,30);
        NSLog(@"%f---%f",cell.center.x,cell.center.y);

        [cell addSubview:tableButton];
        cell.textLabel.text=[TableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];
        cell.textLabel.hidden=YES;
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        return cell;

    }
```